# Data-defined override in SLD possible?

Tags: geoserver, sld

In QGIS I can adjust the width of a linestring layer by data-defined override using the values (in meters) of the attirbute table.

[image]

I'd like to the same thing in GeoServer in  a SLD file. Is that possible? I didn't find anything on the web so far...

Answer (score 3):

You can use math functions in your SLD, technically the standard restricts the places but GeoServer is very relaxed about it, so:

```
     <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
            <ogc:Mul><ogc:PropertyName>cat</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Mul>
          </CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
```

Produces a map like this:

[image]

That's sized in pixels, but you can [specify map units](https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/uom.html) of Metres or Feet if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

If the WMS is SLD enabled (GeoServer supports this, but must be enabled by the service provider), then you can pass SLD as part of a GetMap request using either SLD_BODY (passing the SLD as url encoded content) or SLD (passing a URL pointing to an SLD file accessible to the WMS server).

You can append to existing style, or replace the style.